# Resolving variables in remote ArgoCD applications

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I am using some ArgoCD applications and Helm charts that reside on a GitHub repo. Everytime I need to deploy them I need to clone, populate the values, push and trigger ArgoCD by applying the root application.

The root application then has a reference to other helm and argo applications.

My question: is there a way to populated paramaters or environment variables in ArgoCD so it takes care of substituting them inside helm charts and applications?

What is a better way than cloning, populating variables, pushing and triggering the argocd app?

Comment: you want to add more implicit behavior to an already implicit tool (ie helm) - your source of truth is becoming super complex and you are losing simplicity....beware. GitOps is intended to be declarative/explicit so the source of truth is well understood. To answer your question, I believe you CAN add env vars and reference them in app manifests, this PR enabled it recently https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/pull/10213

Comment: We're currently implementing this functionality into Reliza Hub that would allow dynamic values substitution, you can find me at devopscommunity.org to discuss more.

Comment: An example might help. In general, clone/update/push is fundamental to GitOps (though it can be automated so it's less cumbersome). But maybe you're not trying to avoid git, you're just trying to avoid editing a particular thing in git?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using the [App-of-Apps pattern](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/cluster-bootstrapping/) - i.e. an application which calls a custom Helm chart which generates ArgoCD applications resources (i.e. Kubernetes resources of `kind: Application` which ArgoCD understands).

The root ArgoCD application can be based off an environment e.g. `dev`, `staging`, `test` etc.

Let's assume we have 3 repos:

1. **Argo-Config** - holds *environment* applications / config only.
2. **Argo-App-of-Apps** - holds our custom Helm chart for generating ArgoCD applications. This chart is called by environment specific `Application` K8S resources in the **Argo-Config** repo.
3. **Helm-Charts** - holds all the application Helm charts e.g. for PostgreSQL, Redis, your micro-services etc.

A simple environment Application (in **Argo-Config** repo) could be e.g. `dev-environment.yaml` as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: dev-environment
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: argocd
    server: https://dev.some.kubernetes.cluster
  project: default
  source:
    targetRevision: main
    repoURL: https://github.com/Acme-Org/Argo-App-of-Apps.git
    path: "helm"
    helm:
      values: |
        apps: [redis, postgres]
        spec:
          env: dev
          server: https://dev.some.kubernetes.cluster
          hostname: dev.myapplication.acme.org
        postgres: 
          hostname: dev.database.local
          port: 5432
        redis:
          hostname: dev.redis.local
        ...
```

When this application is added to ArgoCD, it will call App-of-Apps chart.

The OP mentioned ...

> *My question: is there a way to populated parameters or environment variables in ArgoCD so it takes care of substituting them inside helm charts and applications?*

This can be achieved by over-ridding the `spec.source.helm.values` field which in the above example is:

```yaml
apps: [postgres, redis]
spec:
  env: dev
  hostname: dev.myapplication.acme.org
postgres: 
  hostname: dev.database.local
  port: 5432
...
```

The fields we have added include:

- `apps` - what are we installing? For example, Redis, PostgreSQL.
- `spec` - this field can be propagated to all target Helm charts defined and is useful to store important / high-level config.
- `postgres` - ad-hoc config which specific helm charts can make use of.

So how does our custom **Argo-App-of-Apps** Helm chart use these fields?

In the **Argo-App-of-Apps** repo (in a `helm` folder), the following files should exist:

```
helm
  templates
    applications.yaml
  Chart.yaml
  values.yaml
```

Let's look at each file:

##### `Chart.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: app-of-apps
version: 1.0.0
```

##### `values.yaml`

```yaml
applications:
  postgres:
    - name: postgres-{ENV}
      repo: https://github.com/Acme-Org/Helm-Charts.git
      branch: main
      path: helm/postgres
      namespace: postgres
      helmValues: |
        postgresql:
          fullnameOverride: "postgres-{ENV}"
          postgresqlMaxConnections: 2000
          containerPorts:
            postgresql: {{ .Values.postgres.port }}
  redis:
    - name: redis-{ENV}
      repo: https://github.com/Acme-Org/Helm-Charts.git
      branch: main
      path: helm/redis
      namespace: redis
      helmValues: |
        redis:
          nameOverride: "redis-{ENV}"
```

The `values.yaml` file defines which applications the **App-of-Apps** helm Chart can create. The top level `applications` field consists of app names (`postgres`, `redis` etc) and this corresponds to the `apps` field set in the environment application.

Under each app name is a list of one (or more) Helm charts which this application will deploy.

The fields in each application are pretty self-explanatory: -

- `name` - name of application which must be unique. Note the `{ENV}` which the template will replace with the value of `spec.env` (e.g. `dev`).
- `repo` - repo that the application helm chart resides.
- `branch` - branch of repo.
- `path` - location in the repo of the target helm chart.
- `namespace` - target namespace to deploy helm chart.
- `helmValues` - this gives us the ability to override Helm values and also make use of Helm values from the environment application.

If we look at the PostgreSQL `helmValues`:

```yaml
      helmValues: |
        postgresql:
          fullnameOverride: "postgres-{ENV}"
          postgresqlMaxConnections: 2000
          containerPorts:
            postgresql: {{ .Values.postgres.port }}
```

This example uses 2 from the environment `helm.values` i.e.

```yaml
apps: [postgres, redis]
spec:
  env: dev              <------ search/replace of {ENV}
  hostname: dev.myapplication.acme.org
postgres: 
  hostname: dev.database.local 
  port: 5432            <------
```

In the PostgreSQL example, when the **Argo-App-of-Apps** chart renders out an application it should produce the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: 'postgres-dev'
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    server: https://dev.some.kubernetes.cluster
    namespace: 'postgres'
  source:
    repoURL: 'https://github.com/Acme-Org/Helm-Charts.git'
    targetRevision: 'main'
    path: 'helm/postgres'
    helm:
      values: |
        spec:
          env: dev
          hostname: dev.myapplication.acme.org
        postgresql:
          fullnameOverride: "postgres-dev"
          postgresqlMaxConnections: 2000
          containerPorts:
            postgresql: 5432
  project: default
```

This is achieved in our final file in the **Argo-App-of-Apps** repo i.e.:

##### `templates/application.yaml`

```yaml
{{ range $app, $applications := .Values.applications }}
{{ if has $app $.Values.apps }}
{{ range $application := $applications }}
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: '{{ $application.name | replace "{ENV}" $.Values.spec.env }}'
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    server: {{ $.Values.spec.server }}
    namespace: '{{ $application.namespace | replace "{ENV}" $.Values.spec.env }}'
  source:
    repoURL: '{{ $application.repo }}'
    targetRevision: '{{ $application.branch }}'
    path: '{{ $application.path }}'
    helm:
      values: |
        spec:
          {{- toYaml $.Values.spec | nindent 10 }}
        {{- if $application.helmValues }}
        {{- tpl $application.helmValues $ | nindent 8 | replace "{ENV}" $.Values.spec.env }}
        {{- end }}
  project: default
---
{{- end}}
{{- end}}
{{- end}}
```

Note, the loop (`range`), followed by an `if` statement followed by another loop (`range`). This loops over each application type  (`redis`, `postgres`, etc) and checks that it exists in the `apps` field (defined per env). The final loop iterates over each Helm chart specified in the app of apps `values.yaml` file.

Other interesting things include search/replace of `{ENV}` with the value of `spec.env`:

```yaml
  name: '{{ $application.name | replace "{ENV}" $.Values.spec.env }}'
```

Also, the `spec` field gets propagated to all target Helm charts:

```yaml
    helm:
      values: |
        spec:
          {{- toYaml $.Values.spec | nindent 10 }}
```

It also treats the `helmValues` field of each application as a mini template using the `tpl` function (ref https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function):

```yaml
        {{- if $application.helmValues }}
        {{- tpl $application.helmValues $ | nindent 8 | replace "{ENV}" $.Values.spec.env }}
        {{- end }}
```

Using the `tpl` function allowed us to declare a mini template inside the app-of-apps `value.yaml` file. For example, if we look again at the `helmValues` value of the PostgreSQL example:

```yaml
applications:
  postgres:
    - name: postgres-{ENV}
      ...
      helmValues: |
        postgresql:
          fullnameOverride: "postgres-{ENV}"
          postgresqlMaxConnections: 2000
          containerPorts:
            postgresql: {{ .Values.postgres.port }}
```

This ensured `{{ .Values.postgres.port }}` gets converted properly when executed.

## Summary

So the above is a rather simple example of how the **app-of-apps pattern** can be very useful and enable multiple environments to create applications in a DRY / re-usable manner (and inject environment specific properties to target Helm charts).

Note, this can be extended to support other ArgoCD functionality such as syncPolicy, ignoreDifferences, Helm values files and even packaged Helm charts (to support versioning between environments).